# Parse Nested JSON and insert list items with values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
<ul>
<li><a href="" class="edit">a list item</a></li>  
<li><a href="" class="edit">a list item</a></li>    
<li><a href="" class="edit">a list item</a></li>  
<li><a href="" class="edit">a list item</a></li>  
<li><a href="" class="edit">a list item</a></li>  
<li><a href="" class="edit">a list item</a></li>
</ul>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "collection": [
        {
            "snapshot_id": 5110,
            "keyframe_id": 601
        },
        {
            "snapshot_id": 5100,
            "keyframe_id": 610
        },
        {
            "snapshot_id": 5130,
            "keyframe_id": 614
        },
        {
            "snapshot_id": 5142,
            "keyframe_id": 616
        },
        {
            "snapshot_id": 5156,
            "keyframe_id": 617
        },
        {
            "snapshot_id": 5178,
            "keyframe_id": 619
        }
    ]
}
```

Given the list items here and the JSON response, how would one access each keyframe_id of the nest element and insert in the href as such:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="601" class="edit">a list item</a></li>    
<li><a href="610" class="edit">a list item</a></li>  
<li><a href="614" class="edit">a list item</a></li>  
<li><a href="616" class="edit">a list item</a></li>  
<li><a href="617" class="edit">a list item</a></li>
<li><a href="619" class="edit">a list item</a></li>
```

Comment: You parse it into a JavaScript object, iterate over the array in `collection` and access each objects `keyframe_id` property.

Comment: @FelixKling or you do what you did in a comment in another question about an hour ago and use the function parameter version of `.attr()` on the collection of `<a>` elements ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak: True :D I was so focused on parsing the JSON...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very simple way:

```
var collection = json.collection;
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    $("ul > li:eq(" + i + ") > a").attr("href", collection[i].keyframe_id);
}
```

Or vice versa:

```
$("ul > li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).children("a").attr("href", json.collection[i].keyframe_id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the absolute simplest way:

```
$('ul a').attr('href', function(i) {
   return json.collection[i].keyframe_id;
});
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/46QDg/

Do use a more specific selector if you need to!